# Admob and GooglePlayGames not working together

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins, admob, google-play-games

I am using the following plugins in my Unity android game:

1) Admob

2) Google Play Games

3) Unity IAP

I use the latest versions of all plugins.
Unity IAP plugin is not causing any problem and is working fine. Google Play Games do work if there is no Admob. And Admob works when there is no Google Play Games. But Admob and GooglePlayGames is not working together.
I am getting the following error when I try to build my Unity project:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
>   C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M
>   -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools"
>
> ### -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar"
>
> stderr[ Uncaught translation error:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient; Uncaught
>   translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;
>   Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   already added:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$zza;
>   Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/zza; Uncaught
>   translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/zzb; Uncaught translation
>   error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/zzc; Uncaught translation
>   error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/actions/ItemListIntents; Uncaught translation
>   error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/actions/NoteIntents; Uncaught translation
>   error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/actions/ReserveIntents;
>
> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Translation has been interrupted  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:614)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:310)   at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runDx(Main.java:288)    at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:244)     at
>   com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:95)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:130) Caused by:
>   java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors   at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:606)  ...
>   9 more ] stdout[ processing archive C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity
>   Projects\Shapes\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleAIDL\libs.\classes.jar...
>   processing com/android/vending/billing/BuildConfig.class... processing
>   com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.class... processing
>   com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub.class...
>   processing
>   com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class...
>   processing archive C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity
>   Projects\Shapes\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GooglePlay\libs.\classes.jar...
>   processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/ActivityLauncher.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BillingServiceManager.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BillingServiceManager$1.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BillingServiceManager$1$1.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BillingServiceManager$1$2.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BillingServiceManager$2.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BillingServiceProcessor.class...
>   processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/BuildConfig.class...
>   processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/Consts.class... processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/Consts$PurchaseState.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/Consts$ResponseCode.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayBillingUnAvailableException.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$1.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$2.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$3.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$4.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$5.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$6.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$7.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$8.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/GooglePlayPurchasing$Features.class...
>   processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IActivityLauncher.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IBillingServiceManager.class...
>   processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabException.class...
>   processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper.class...
>   processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$1.class...
>   processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$2.class...
>   processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$2$1.class...
>   processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$3.class...
>   processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$3$1.class...
>   processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$4.class...
>   processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$5.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$OnConsumeFinishedListener.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$OnConsumeMultiFinishedListener.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$OnIabSetupFinishedListener.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabHelper$QueryInventoryFinishedListener.class...
>   processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/IabResult.class...
>   processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/Inventory.class...
>   processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/Purchase.class...
>   processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/PurchaseActivity.class...
>   processing
>   com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/PurchaseFailedEvent.class...
>   processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/SkuDetails.class...
>   processing com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/VRPurchaseActivity.class...
>   processing archive C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity
>   Projects\Shapes\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\admoblib-release\libs.\classes.jar...
>   processing com/admob/plugin/AdmobHandler.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/AdmobListenerProxy.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/AdmobNativeAd.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/AdmobNativeAd$1.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/AdmobNativeAd$2.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/AdmobNativeAd$3.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/AdmobNativeAd$4.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/AdmobUnityPlugin.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/AdmobUnityPlugin$1.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/BannerHandler.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/BannerHandler$1.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/BannerHandler$2.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/BannerHandler$3.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/BannerHandler$BannerPosition.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/BuildConfig.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/ClassicBannerHandler.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/ClassicBannerHandler$1.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/IAdmobListener.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/IAdmobNativeAdListener.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/InterstitialHandler.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/InterstitialHandler$1.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/InterstitialHandler$2.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/InterstitialHandler$3.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/NativeBannerHandler.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/NativeBannerHandler$1.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/VideoHandler.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/VideoHandler$1.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/VideoHandler$2.class... processing
>   com/admob/plugin/VideoHandler$3.class... processing archive
>   C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity
>   Projects\Shapes\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-compat-25.2.0\libs.\classes.jar...
>   processing android/support/compat/BuildConfig.class... processing
>   android/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoJellyBeanImpl.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoJellyBeanMr2Impl.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoStubImpl.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatJellyBean.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatJellyBeanMr2.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/animation/AnimatorCompatHelper.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/animation/AnimatorListenerCompat.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/animation/AnimatorProvider.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/animation/AnimatorUpdateListenerCompat.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/animation/GingerbreadAnimatorCompatProvider.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/animation/GingerbreadAnimatorCompatProvider$GingerbreadFloatValueAnimator.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/animation/GingerbreadAnimatorCompatProvider$GingerbreadFloatValueAnimator$1.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/animation/HoneycombMr1AnimatorCompatProvider.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/animation/HoneycombMr1AnimatorCompatProvider$AnimatorListenerCompatWrapper.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/animation/HoneycombMr1AnimatorCompatProvider$HoneycombValueAnimatorCompat.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/animation/HoneycombMr1AnimatorCompatProvider$HoneycombValueAnimatorCompat$1.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/animation/ValueAnimatorCompat.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.class... processing
>   android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat$1.class... processing
>   android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat$OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback21Impl.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback23Impl.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback23Impl$1.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatApi21.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatApi21$SharedElementCallback21.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatApi21$SharedElementCallbackImpl.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatApi22.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatApi23.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatApi23$OnSharedElementsReadyListenerBridge.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatApi23$RequestPermissionsRequestCodeValidator.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatApi23$SharedElementCallback23.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatApi23$SharedElementCallbackImpl.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatApi23$SharedElementCallbackImpl$1.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatHoneycomb.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatJB.class... processing
>   android/support/v4/app/ActivityManagerCompat.class... processing
>   android/support/v4/app/ActivityManagerCompatKitKat.class... processing
>   android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat.class... processing
>   android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat$ActivityOptionsImpl21.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat$ActivityOptionsImpl23.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat$ActivityOptionsImpl24.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat$ActivityOptionsImplJB.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat21.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat23.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat24.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompatJB.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/AppOpsManagerCompat.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/AppOpsManagerCompat$AppOpsManager23.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/AppOpsManagerCompat$AppOpsManagerImpl.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/AppOpsManagerCompat23.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/BundleCompat.class... processing
>   android/support/v4/app/BundleCompatGingerbread.class... processing
>   android/support/v4/app/BundleCompatJellybeanMR2.class... processing
>   android/support/v4/app/BundleUtil.class... processing
>   android/support/v4/app/INotificationSideChannel.class... processing
>   android/support/v4/app/INotificationSideChannel$Stub.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationBuilderWithActions.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationBuilderWithBuilderAccessor.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Action.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Action$1.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Action$Builder.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Action$Extender.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Action$WearableExtender.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$BigPictureStyle.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$BigTextStyle.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$BuilderExtender.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$CarExtender.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$CarExtender$UnreadConversation.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$CarExtender$UnreadConversation$1.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$CarExtender$UnreadConversation$Builder.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Extender.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$InboxStyle.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$MessagingStyle.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$MessagingStyle$Message.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImpl.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImplApi20.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImplApi21.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImplApi24.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImplBase.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImplHoneycomb.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImplIceCreamSandwich.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImplJellybean.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImplKitKat.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Style.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$WearableExtender.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompatApi20.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompatApi20$Builder.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompatApi21.class...
>   processing
>   android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompatApi21$Builder.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompatApi23.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompatApi24.class...
>   processing android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompatApi24$Bu

I have seen similar issues posted in stackoverflow and GitHub. However, the solution mentioned there didn't workout for me.

Could someone please help me fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This error was shown because there's a failure in **DEX tool** while running android programs that are compiled in `.dex` file (which are in turn zipped into a single `.apk` file on the device). This tool is being executed by Unity as part of the Android Process. The error happens when there are multiple libraries (multiple identical classes) that are being added to the APK.

> stderr[ Uncaught translation error:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient; Uncaught
>   translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:

Therefore, you just need to delete the duplicated libraries, keep the latest versions and use the play resolver to update them to new versions.

See full [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start) of Google Mobile Ads SDK for Unity.

You can also check a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOW2-VkIXKtXxFkZ8zGdsinHzteTbDIxR) for best practice of Google Play Game Services and Admob Plugin in Unity.

Comment: I dont see any duplicate libraries. Also, I am using the latest versions. The guy in the video you shared speaks some alien language. Therefore, I cant understand anything. PS: Admob is working fine when there is no GooglePlayGames and vice versa.